# What does it mean by a subset of an arbitrary group is $O(K^9)$-approximate subset?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, additive-combinatorics

Let $G$ be any group and $A,B\subset G$ are finite subsets of $G$.
We define $AB:=\{ab |a \in A, b\in B\}$. In a similar fashion we can define $A^2, A^3, \dotsc, A^n,\dotsc$.

Now, we say $A$ is a $K$-approximate subset of $G$ if there is a $ X\subset G$ with $|X| \leq K$ such that $A^2 \subset  XA$.

Another way to view this definition is to consider $|A^2|$ is at most $K|A|$, where $K$ is called the ***doubling constant***.

Now my question: what is the significance of saying that $B\subset G$ is $O(K^9)$-approximate subset of $G$?

(cf. Proposition 2.5.5, Introduction to approximate groups by Matthew C.H. Tointon)

Comment: Your question could use some focus: it is rather broad and vague to ask "what is the significance" of a definition. But since you have a textbook on this topic, I presume that the significance is discussed further in that book. For example, perhaps there are examples and applications of approximate subsets. Is there something in that further discussion that might be relevant to your post, and that you can use to give your question more focus?

Comment: @LeeMosher Let me elaborate the term 'Significance'. It can be shown that if I choose any subset A of size k from {1,2,...,n}, expectation of |A+A|/|A|=(2k+1+o(1))/k^2 as n goes to infinity. Here, the significance of 'little oh' is there will be some error of estimation if k is not large enough, and the expectation stabilizes at (2k+1/k^2) if k is large enough.  Note: A+A is the abelian analogy of general A^2 setting.